# Jupyter notebook failed to process training data

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a classification on an image with the CNN algorithm. When I tried to run it on jupyter notebook(anaconda) it didn't work, but when I run it on google colabs it worked [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9eQD.png)

Comment: As the error message suggests: Install SciPy!

Comment: Run in a cell in your notebook `%conda install scipy` or `%pip install scipy`, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 0):

Google colab default has scipy version 1.4.1.

In jupyter notebook you need to install Scipy.

```
!pip install scipy
```

Follow the instructions mention [here](https://scipy.org/install/) to install Scipy